# Integrating Apache Superset and Apache Drill

Tags: sqlalchemy, configure, apache-drill, apache-superset

I installed Apache Drill through the link in the [Drill Documentation](https://drill.apache.org/docs/starting-the-web-ui/). Apache Drill works fine. I also installed and got Apache Superset running using docker. Superset also works totally fine.

But my goal is to integrate Superset and Drill together. The only tutorial I was able to find was a [tutorial from Dataist](http://thedataist.com/visualize-anything-with-superset-and-drill/). When following this tutorial they ask us to add a database.

Since I am running both Drill and Superset in my local machine they ask us to type drill+sadrill://localhost:8047/dfs/test?use_ssl=False as the SQLAlchemy URI. They ask us to test the connection by pressing test connection.

When pressing test connection I get an error message as follows.

`ERROR: {"error": "Connection failed!\n\nThe error message returned was:\nCan't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:drill.sadrill", "stacktrace": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/home/superset/superset/views/core.py\", line 1755, in testconn\n    engine = database.get_sqla_engine(user_name=username)\n  File \"/home/superset/superset/utils/core.py\", line 132, in __call__\n    value = self.func(*args, **kwargs)\n  File \"/home/superset/superset/models/core.py\", line 911, in get_sqla_engine\n    return create_engine(url, **params)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py\", line 435, in create_engine\n    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py\", line 61, in create\n    entrypoint = u._get_entrypoint()\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/url.py\", line 172, in _get_entrypoint\n    cls = registry.load(name)\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py\", line 240, in load\n    \"Can't load plugin: %s:%s\" % (self.group, name)\nsqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:drill.sadrill\n"}`

Can someone figure out why I am getting this error. And also if there are any other tutorials to follow which give a better idea on how to set up Drill and superset.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar issue while trying to connect elasticsearch. I guess the docker image you used was amancevice/superset. This issue cause because your image is not using the latest SQLAlchemy, SQLAlchemy-Utils packages. Upgrade or reinstall these packages to fix the issue.

To uninstall:

pip uninstall SQLAlchemy
pip uninstall SQLAlchemy-Utils

To install again (latest version):

pip install SQLAlchemy
pip install SQLAlchemy-Utils

I have reported this issue here https://github.com/amancevice/docker-superset/issues/158 maybe it get fixed with the upcoming images.