# How to connect apache-superset with apache-drill?

Tags: docker, pip, apache-superset, apache-drill

I'm trying to connect [superset](https://superset.apache.org/) (v2021.10.0, using docker) with [drill](https://drill.apache.org/) (in embedded mode).

[This tutorial](https://thedataist.com/visualize-anything-with-superset-and-drill/) mentions that, when drill is in embedded mode,  the query string is `drill+sadrill://localhost:8047/dfs?use_ssl=False`. However, when I test the connection I get this error

[image: superseterror]

The logs show this :

```
superset_app             | DEBUG:superset.stats_logger:[stats_logger] (incr) test_connection_error.NoSuchModuleError
superset_app             | DEBUG:superset.stats_logger:[stats_logger] (incr) DatabaseRestApi.test_connection.error
superset_app             | DEBUG:superset.stats_logger:[stats_logger] (timing) DatabaseRestApi.test_connection.time | 46.48779600029229
```

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58163150/integrating-apache-superset-and-apache-drill) and the error I'm getting I assumed that the error is because it's missing the `sqlalchemy-drill` dependency, so I tried to install sqlalchemy-drill adding `sqlalchemy-drill==0.1.dev` to the `base.txt` file used by docker to install pip dependencies. But I'm still getting the same error.

Is my assumption right and it's missing the `sqlalchemy-drill` dependency? How can it be added? If no, what's the right way of running superset (on docker) with drill?

### Update

After following the instructions from @ʈᵃᵢ's link I see this in the docker-compose's output:

```
superset_worker         | Successfully built sqlalchemy-drill
superset_worker_beat    | Successfully built sqlalchemy-drill
superset_app            | logging was configured successfully
superset_app            | INFO:superset.utils.logging_configurator:logging was configured successfully
superset_init           | Installing collected packages: sqlalchemy-drill
superset_init           | Successfully installed sqlalchemy-drill-0.1.dev0
superset_worker         | Installing collected packages: sqlalchemy-drill
superset_worker_beat    | Installing collected packages: sqlalchemy-drill
superset_worker         | Successfully installed sqlalchemy-drill-0.1.dev0
superset_worker_beat    | Successfully installed sqlalchemy-drill-0.1.dev0
```

But the `Could not load database driver: DrillEngineSpec` is still happening. (Tested with 0.3.dev0 too).

### Update 2:

After pulling the latest sources from master (including the @ʈᵃᵢ's fix) I was able to load the driver. I also needed to change `localhost` to `host.docker.internal`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you’re using docker-compose take a look at this doc for how to add local packages
https://github.com/apache/superset/tree/master/docker#local-packages

Comment: Thanks for the response! After adding the `sqlalchemy-drill` as mentioned on that link, and rebuilding docker compose, it still throws `ERROR: Could not load database driver: DrillEngineSpec`

Comment: Which version of superset are you using?

Comment: If you're using the `docker-compose-non-dev.yml` I fixed an issue with installing local overrides recently, https://github.com/apache/superset/pull/13926. I would pull the latest master and try again.

Comment: That made the driver load, Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide an example to add to local packages now, im facing the same error: sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:drill.sadrill